# How to find index of form from FormArray that contain error in angular?

Tags: angular, forms, validation, angular-reactive-forms, formarray

I am working with one complex form in angular and I need some help. let me explain my scenario in detail.

I have one formArray like this :

```
let slides = new FormArray([]);
slides.push(getNewSlide())
slides.push(getNewSlide())
slides.push(getNewSlide())
slides.push(getNewSlide())

function getNewSlide() {
  return new FormGroup({
    name: new FormControl("", [Validators.required]),
    image: new FormControl("", [Validators.required])
  })
}
```

Above form will look like this :

```
slides = [
  { name: "ram", image: "a.png" },
  { name: "shyam", image: "b.png" },
  { name: "", image: "c.png" },             <== here is error. name is required so index should be 2
  { name: "ghanshyam", image: "d.png" },
]
```

I want to find index of the form from `FormArray` that contain any error, But I don't know how to do that. One important thing is that, this form can be nested. like one `FormGroup` can contain another `FormGroup` or `FormArray`

anyone know about it to deep scan whole form and find index of first error place (index of form), then please answer here. I will appreciate your ideas.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could loop through the formArray controls and check for errors. Like this:

```
findFirstInvalidControlInFormArray() {
    const index = (this.slides as FormArray).controls.findIndex(
      (control) => control.invalid
    );
    console.log(index);
  }
```

If the index is -1 it means, all controls are valid.